# Matrix Factorization In Matlab using Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, matrix-factorization

I have to factorize `Matrix` R[m*n] to two low-rank Matrices (U[K*m] and V[K*n]), I do this for predicting missing values of R by U and V.
     [image: Matrix Factorization]

The problem is, for factorizing **R** I can't use `Matlab` factorization methods, so I have to work on objective function which minimizes the `sum-of-squared-errors` for enhancing factorization accuracy:
     [image: Objective Function]
details are shown below:

[image]

---

My Question in this post is how to **minimize function F** in `Matlab` Using **[Stochastic Gradient Descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent)** method to decompose R into U and V matrices.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: **Stochastic Gradient Descent** actually computes derivatives for F on each row of U' and each columns of V, I can't understand derivative for a matrix column or row!!! :((

Comment: To confirm, Matlab's [`nnmf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nnmf.html) won't work for you? I believe that it use some form of stochastic search.

Comment: @horcher, [nnmf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nnmf.html) won't work me because it doesn't accept NaN or missing entries in R matrix. Actually I have to implement matrix factorization on my own.

Comment: Hi @oMiD, I am also looking for a way to impute missing values using matrix factorization. In my case, I am using a binary matrix so cannot replace those missing values by 0. Could you please explain to me how you replaced missing values in your input matrix and obtained those back after factorization? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured out with help of [this page](http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/comment-page-1/#comment-48207) :)
I explain the approach in some steps:

1. Create U[k*m] and V[k*n] and fill them arbitrarily
2. Compute derivatives for objective function on Ui and Vj
3. Do gradient descent as follows:

   while (your criteria satisfies(optimizing error function F))
   {
      Ui=Ui+a(U'i);
      Vj=Vj+a(V'j);
      Evaluate F using new values of Ui and Vj;
   }
4. With the minimum F , take U and V, compute transpose(U)*V and the
   result is estimated R (**a** is **step size** or **learning rate**)